# Can we say anything regarding the derivative at zero of a holomorphic map from the unit disk to itself without a condition of Schwarz's lemma?

Tags: complex-analysis

Suppose that I have $f$ to be a holomorphic map from the unit disk to itself. Schwarz lemma asserts that $|f'(0)|\leq 1$, but it assumes $f(0)=0$. If we drop this assumption, can we still say that $|f'(0)|\leq 1$? I can't seem to find a counterexample or a proof.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [Schwarz–Pick theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Schwarz_lemma#Schwarz.E2.80.93Pick_theorem)
is a generalization of the Schwarz Lemma. If $f$ is a holomorphic
function from the unit disk into itself then

$$
\frac{|f'(z)|}{1-|f(z)|^{2}} \leq \frac{1}{1-|z|^{2}} \, .
$$

In particular,
$$
|f'(0)| \le 1-|f(0)|^{2} \le 1 \, .
$$

*Equality* can only hold if $f(0) = 0$ and consequently, $f(z)=az$
for a constant $a$ with $|a|=1$.